# connecting python to javascript for two-direction communication

Tags: javascript, python, json, connection, request

I would like to serve queries from a javascript code by python. But I am not experienced in this field at all. What I would like to build is something like this:

> **1. request.js**:

```
open_connection('server.py');
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
    document.write(request_next_number());
close_connection('server.py')
```

> **2. server.py**

```
x = 0
while connected:
    if request:
        send(x)
        x = x + 1
```

I heard about JSON, but don't know if I should use it. (?)

Could you please give me some code examples or guides how to implement the two files above?

Comment: You're looking for websockets.

Comment: Why would you use python? Use `node.js`.

Comment: @enginefree - you may prefer node.js but many people use python as the back end.

Comment: @enginefree Yes, I might use that, however the core part of my code which is course not what the example is here, has been already written, thus I wouldn't change to node.js, which I don't know at all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is a socket server on the `python` end and a client/request server on the javascript end.

For the python server side, refer to [`SocketServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html), (example taken from there as well), one thing you have to make sure is to have the socket go past `NAT` (possibly port forwarding). One other alternative is [`Twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) which is a very powerful framework, i believe it has functionality to send data through `NAT`.

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

On the `JavaScript` there are many frameworks that allow socket connections, here are a few

- [`Socket IO`](http://socket.io/)

Example:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

- You can even use [`HTML5 Web Sockets`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Example:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://IPAddress:Port');
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};
```

- Also, take a look at a part of this book , Chapter 22 of `Javascript: The Definitive Guide` , https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-22/web-sockets
- Finally, take a look at [`jssockets`](http://code.google.com/p/jssockets/)

Example:

```
_jssocket.setCallBack(event, callback);
_jssocket.connect(ip,port);
_jssocket.write(message);
_jssocket.disconnect();
```

Hope this help!

Comment: @gen BTW I have once used `python` as a socket-server and sent data with `C#`, it was very fluid.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed anwser, I will try to implement it somehow :)

Comment: I looked after Socket IO, it was necessary to install it with code 'npm install',  I looked after it and it's part of node.js, does it mean that I need to use a huge package of js library to make it working?

Comment: Not sure. But the modules that I used with node install, usually just compile into medium size package.

Comment: Thats what I would use in your situation. No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

An example with Web Socket that i have used to transfer image to a web server and stream my screen.

**stream.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset = utf-8>

<html>
    <header>
        <title>Stream</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/request.js"></script>
    </header>
    <body onload="doLoad()">
        <div id="canvasWrapper">
            <canvas id="display"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**request.js**

```
var disp;
var dispCtx;
var im;
var ws;

function doLoad() {
    disp = document.getElementById("display");
    dispCtx = disp.getContext("2d");
    im = new Image();
    im.onload = function() {
    disp.setAttribute("width", im.width);
    disp.setAttribute("height", im.height);
    dispCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
    im.src = "img/img_not_found.png";
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:50007");
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        im.src = "data:image/png;base64," + evt.data;
    }
}
```

**server.py**

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
import base64
import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

        def hello():
            with open("/var/www/html/img/image.png", "rb") as image_file:
                encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
            self.sendMessage(encoded_string.encode('utf8'))
            self.factory.reactor.callLater(0.2, hello)

        # start sending messages every 20ms ..
        hello()

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

        # echo back message verbatim
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://127.0.0.1:50007")
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
    # factory.setProtocolOptions(maxConnections=2)

    # note to self: if using putChild, the child must be bytes...

    reactor.listenTCP(50007, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

You will need **autobahn** (you can install it with `pip install autobahn`)