# How to read/pass a js var to python script?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7

I have a .js file (test.js) with a bunch of calculations and variables. Let's just say 1 number (var1) and 1 array (var2).

I also have a .py file (test2.py) with a bunch of stuff. Is there any way to pass (var1) and (var2) so test2.py can read it and do some more work on it?

Is this possible? If so, what would it look like in Python?

Comment: for simplicity I'm going to say you can't do this. If you *really* want to do it, you *could* do it with nodejs and a socket.io server/client interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connecting python to javascript for two direction communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233433/connecting-python-to-javascript-for-two-direction-communication)

Comment: @XanderLuciano how about btw python and HTML?

Comment: @KathyKimLee well HTML is just a markup language so you can parse HTML with python.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this . How Python will know javascript variables ?. No language will  understand the other languages memory structures . There should be some interface(agreement) to make it understand. For example , Java and C can be using JNI (Java Native Interface) .

Answer (score 0):

You can export the variables as JSON from Javascript - how depends on which environment you run the script in (nodejs, browser, ...) - and import them in Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This works the other way, too.

Comment: that's the problem. how do you export the vars from JS to Py?

Comment: How do you run your JS?