# What is the easiest way to establish communication between a python program to a JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, web

I am new to web development and have a JavaScript code I downloaded, I want it to call some python functions to do calculations.
As I research I find a lot of information and I am not sure yet what to do.
I will present to knowledge I have gathered and then ask my questions:

1) In the following issue:
[connecting python to javascript for two-direction communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233433/connecting-python-to-javascript-for-two-direction-communication) , there is an explanation about how to open a python socket using SocketServer, and how to open a JS socket using socketIO... but I didn't understand from this how the connection is established.

2) The best example I have found is that one: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, it seems to explain how to establish a connection using the flask library and the socketIO library.
My problem with this guide is that I'm not sure how to implement it on localHost.

My questions:

1) Can you help me (maybe by referencing to some guide) create a simple program that will establish a two-way connection between a JS and a python programs? for example, when the user clicks on a button it sends a number to the python program, it adds 1 to it, sends it back to the JS program and prints the result to the browser log?

2) I am not sure how to make it work with an actual site. I tries to run the program from the first source and open localHost, but I got an error. how do I make my JS code run with localHost?

3) the JS code I downloaded run on a specific website. I need it to communicate with the program I am writing (it's a machine learning program that should learn to play a game). Does that fact changes the methods needed to solve the first two questions?